# goBack function react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So,  I am having this problem with goBack function "Cannot read property of undefined" I want when I press An arrowBack icon it goes back to MainSettings COMPONENT

```
Parent component

const MainSettings=()=> {
const [isSystemOpen, setIsSystemOpen]= React.useState(false)
const {goBack} = this.props.navigation;


  
    function openSystem(){
        setIsSystemOpen(true)
      }
      function closeSystem(){
        setIsSystemOpen(false)
      }


 return (
        <div className="mainSettings">


<ComputerIcon onClick={openSystem} />
                {isSystemOpen ? <System closeSystem={closeSystem} />: null}
</div>






Child Component

const System =(props)=> {

  
    
    return (
        <div className='mainSystem'>
            <ArrowBackIcon className='arrow'onClick={this.props.navigation.goBack()}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You don't have `this` inside arrow functions and you don't pass any `props`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

You are using `this` in function components. There is no need to use `this` in function components, so just use `props` when you want to reach it.

For example, in your `MainSettings` component, you are trying to get your `props` with `this.props.navigation` which you shouldn't. You can get it with:

```
const MainSettings = (props) => ...
```

and then use like:

```
const { goBack } = props.navigation;
```

You are not passing `goBack` as a prop to your child component. So, you should do it:

```
<System closeSystem={closeSystem} goBack={goBack} />
```

You shouldn't invoke your `goBack` function on your `onClick` handler. You can use the reference:

`<ArrowBackIcon className='arrow' onClick={props.navigation.goBack}`

Comment: I am getting this TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'goBack' of 'props.navigation' as it is undefined.

Comment: This an irrelevant problem to your current question. So, you should check your props if you are getting `navigation`. I believe `navigation` is used with React Native but I don't see it in tags. So, you should be clear. But, this is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent you need useHistory:

```
import { userHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function MainSettings() {
  const history = useHistory();
  function historyGoBack() {
    history.goBack();
  }
  ...
```

Then you can use it in the child component from the parent:

```
  <System closeSystem={closeSystem} back={this.historyGoBack()} />
```

The child component itself modifying your ArrowBackIcon:

```
...
<ArrowBackIcon className='arrow' onClick={this.props.back} />
```

Then clicking on the arrow should go back as you want it to.

Comment: I am getting this TypeError: Object(...) is not a function